# Why is the text I piont to in an Adobe menu invisible?

Tags: adobe-reader

I have Ubuntu 13.10. I recently installed Adobe Reader 9 and the options on the menus are visible, but when I put my mouse over an option it becomes invisible. I think it is highlighting it in white instead of some other color. What do I do about this?